# Sort de lista dependiendo de otra lista Python

Tags: python

Recibirás dos listas: una con strings y/o números y otra con los índices que indican el orden de cada elemento en la lista final.
Deberás ordenar la lista original según la secuencia dada por la segunda lista.
Por ejemplo:

```
#El input:
a b c
1 2 0

#Y el output debe ser:
['c', 'a', 'b']

#Llevo esto de código, pero no se me ocurre qué más hacer:

n1 = input()
n2 = input()
lista1 = n1.split(" ")
lista2 = n2.split(" ")
b = [int(x) for x in lista2]
def funcion(b):
    for i in range (len(b)):
        return int(b[i])
lista1.sort(key=lista1[b[i]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución en python es simple:

```py
lista_ordenada = [x for (i, x) in sorted(zip(lista2, lista1))]
```

Pero me da que se trata de un ejercicio y que la idea es que hagas tú el algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bien sencilla es crear una lista del tamaño de la original, y usar como índice para asignar cada elemento, la lista del orden. Algo así:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']
orden = [1, 2, 0]

lista_ordenada = [None] * len(lista)
for i, o in enumerate(orden):
  lista_ordenada[o] = lista[i]

print(lista_ordenada)

['c', 'a', 'b']
```